# GraphQL query connect to Dutchie API using PHP

Tags: php, wordpress, graphql

I have a store in Dutchie.com. I want to access it's products using API key.
This has to do via Dutchie API using GraphQL integrated with PHP.

**This is the Sample API Key:**

```
public-eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJhdWQiOiJBUEktQ0xJRU5UIiwiZXhwIjozMzE4NjM5Mjc0NSwiaWF0IjoxNjI5NDgzOTQ1LCJpc3MiOiJodHRwczovL2R1dGNoY29tIiwianRpIjoiNGMtOTMyOC00MjhkLWEyYTMtOWQzMTc2ZTUwODY0IiwiZW50ZXJwcmlzZV9pZChLWExYTctNDM3OC05NWY4LTNlYzVzBiNSIsInV1aWQiOiI0M2ZlMjdkNy1iZWU2LTQxOTgtYWNhMi03N2Y5Y2I3MjI5MGIifQ.hCQWpcQ5uhKnZOSVQDA5SCMkx5kopC7H3upeU-1jMpg
```

**This is the GraphQL Ping mutation.**

```
mutation Ping {
  ping {
    id,
    time
  }
}
```

**Dutchie End Point:** https://plus.dutchie.com/plus/2021-07/graphql

**http header parameter**
{
"Authorization":"Bearer API KEY HERE"
}

**Ping output**
[image]

Basically I want to run GraphQL query in my PHP page. I'll add into my WordPress page later.

I have tried [php-graphql-client](https://github.com/mghoneimy/php-graphql-client) php library.
Can someone help me to do this using above library or another one really appreciate. I wasted too much time for this as I have only few knowledge of GraphQL.

This is the code what I have tried.

```
$client = new Client(
    'https://plus.dutchie.com/plus/2021-07/graphql',
    ['Authorization => Bearer API Key here']
);
 

 
// Create the GraphQL mutation
$gql = (new Mutation('Ping'))
    ->setSelectionSet(
        [
            'id',
            'time',
        ]
    );

// Run query to get results
try {
    $results = $client->runQuery($gql);
}
catch (QueryError $exception) {

    // Catch query error and desplay error details
    print_r($exception->getErrorDetails());
    exit;
}

// Display original response from endpoint
var_dump($results->getResponseObject());

// Display part of the returned results of the object
var_dump($results->getData()->pokemon);

// Reformat the results to an array and get the results of part of the array
$results->reformatResults(true);
print_r($results->getData()['data']);
```

**Error what I got.**
https://github.com/guzzle/psr7/blob/master/src/MessageTrait.php
[image]

Comment: Where exactly are you stuck? What specifically is the problem? This is way too broad (and you have enough rep points that you really ought to understand that already, if I may say so). Please read [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question) if you need a bit more detail.

Comment: I stucked creating the php code/function structure to send queries to the dutchie endpoint.

Comment: In what way are you stuck, precisely? What have you tried? What went wrong? There are usage examples in the php-graphql client documentation

Comment: P.S. Why on earth have you published your API key here for the world to see??? It's _your_ key, but now other people can use it. Delete that key from your account and generate a new one ASAP

Comment: Added a sample API key here. Not the actual one.

Comment: I updated the question by adding the code what I tried.

Comment: `Added a sample API key here. Not the actual one`...ok. Well then it's completely irrelevant to the question, you can just remove it.

Comment: `This is the code what I have tried`...ok and, again I'll ask: what exactly is the problem with it? Do you get an error? Unexpected result? Have you done any debugging? Remember we cannot see your screen or read your mind.

Comment: And please paste all code and errors etc as _text_, not pictures. Any textual information should be included as text. Please read [ask] to refresh your memory. And maybe read [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)
 if you don't understand why pictures of text are really unhelpful for those trying to answer the question. Thanks.

Comment: P.S. The usage examples show the header as `['Authorization' => 'Basic xyz']` - i.e. an associative array a key and a value. Your example shows it as a simple array with a single string. That will create a numerically-indexed array, so the key will be `0`, which is an integer, which would then make sense in terms of the error you're getting. Try `['Authorization' => 'Bearer API Key here']` instead. Tempted to close this question as a just a typo mistake.

Comment: @ADyson Thanks for the details. There was a small typo mistake. I was able to fix that once you mentioned. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

**Instead of:**

```
$client = new Client(
    'https://plus.dutchie.com/plus/2021-07/graphql',
    ['Authorization => Bearer API Key here']
);
```

**Try**

```
$client = new Client(
    'https://plus.dutchie.com/plus/2021-07/graphql',
    ['Authorization' => 'Bearer API Key here']
);
```

Comment: Yes, this is the way how I fixed. Thank you Alexis.